# Relative path resolution for CSS links

Tags: html, css, tomcat, hyperlink, relative-path

I've read a lot of topics about absolute and relative paths resolutions in http pages. Unfortunately, I can't figure out what is wrong in my case... So here I am!

My project is a web application built on Spring MVC/Thymeleaf/Bootstrap.
When running my app on my personal computer, css links are not solved. The strange thing is that it is actually working on another computer.

My Bootstrap file is located here: `webapp/css/Bootstrap.css`
My link in html webapp: 
`<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

On one computer, the link is resolved as `http://localhost:8080/css/Bootstrap.css`.
On the other one, the link is `http://localhost:8080/myAppContext/css/Bootstrap.css`.

I do not understand what is wrong with my configuration...

This  is kind of magic for me... The sources are exactly the same, the tomcat version are identical on each computers. Java version are also absolutely the same... The tomcat servlet.xml configuration have no differences. It's look like a mystery! :)

Could you help me please?

Comment: Do you have any [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element at the `<head>`?

Comment: I don't have any <base> element.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally God spoke right to my ear and told me: add a slash...

So when I request my app with a final slash: `http://localhost:8080/myAppContext/` the relative paths are found.

Joy of coding!

Answer (score 0):

For that you should not have trouble posting your application, but if it is in a test phase that happens.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your point. I should not have trouble, but actually, I have. :(

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

this work fine  if the html page is in the "`http://localhost:8080/`" like "`http://localhost:8080/index.html`"

Comment: The application is deployed on a Apache Tomcat Server. 
The index.html is not right after the HTTP port. My URL looks more like: http://localhost:8080/myAppContext/index.html

Comment: then you can use this , <link href="/myAppContext/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/> .

Comment: I don't want to use the app context in my views, because I don't want my controller to return to each views my app context name.